# Declaring a character variable without quotes in C

Tags: c, char

What happens when we declare a character variable without using single quotes? For eg:

```
char ch=5;
char ch= a;
```

Comment: Try asking your C compiler, or the C language standard.

Comment: This is a very bad question. You're expected to have done a minimum of research about the syntax of a language before posting here about it.

Comment: The question doesn't demonstrate much research effort, but finding answer to this question wouldn't actually be easy. There's probably a duplicate here at SO, if someone finds it, please vote to close as dupe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, `char` type is just  an integer number, usually 8 bits wide, signed or unsigned depending on compiler.

"Characters" are just agreement on what these numbers mean, called "text encoding". 8 bit text encodings in common use today are based on [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). From there you can check that value 5 is non-printable control char (called [*ENQ*, with historical meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enquiry_character) which has no practical relevance today except for curiosity), and printable character `'5'` has numeric value 53 in ASCII encoding.

---

Let's explain the two lines of code in your question:

`char ch=5;` defines variable `ch` of type `char`, and initializes it with value `5`, which is a *numeric literal*. It is recognized as such literal, because it starts with a number.

`char ch= a;` defines variable `ch` of type `char`, and initializes it with value of variable `a` (and if there is no `a` defined yet, you get compiler error). `a` here is a symbol name (probably a variable name), recognized as such because it starts with letter character (underscore would also be ok).